# Is there linter for model(inputs) of PyTorch like model.predict(inputs) of TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

My goal is to do object detection. However, YOLOv7 and (hack to create bounding box with feature map) tutorial is using PyTorch.

The problem is: `model(inputs)` do not have typings.

[The code L148-L150](https://github.com/OlgaChernytska/Visual-Inspection/blob/main/utils/helper.py#L148-L150)

```
        out = model(inputs)
        probs, class_preds = torch.max(out[0], dim=-1)
        feature_maps = out[1].to("cpu")
```

The forced me to debug the `helper.py` file to understand what `[0]` and `out[1]` are. Currently, I assume that `out[0]` as the softmax probability and `out[1]` as the feature maps.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is no, in general it is non-trivial to automatically infer the semantic meaning of the outputs of a neural network; this is a product of the semantic meaning of the inputs and the model structure itself. You could reference the Yolo model architecture provided in `model.py` (though as an aside you should not link to external code but rather provide relevant code in your question itself) and investigate the structure of the outputs, then reference the structure of the labeled inputs (as the model by definition is learning to replicate the structure of the labels.)

That being said in your case the output is quite obviously per-class probabilities and class indexes as shown in line 149:

```
probs, class_preds = torch.max(out[0], dim=-1)
```

as the outputs from `torch.max` per pytorch documentation are (maximum value, maximum index).